# deploy azure function from Visual Studio along with class library

Tags: azure, azure-functions, c#-3.0

I have azure function developed using visual studio and this function uses external class library and also the function is having some packages. When I deploy to azure function app and run the function, M getting error 500 internal server error.

Do I need to deploy class library and packages also? if yes how to deploy?

Please help me on this

```
  using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
  using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
  using Newtonsoft.Json;
 using IronPython.Hosting;//for DLHE
 using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;//provides scripting abilities comparable to batch files
using System.Diagnostics;
using IronPython.Compiler;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using DatasetLibrary;
using System.Data;

 namespace ExecutePyCode
   {
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static int Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        int result = 0;

        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        //try
        //{

        var compilerOptions = (PythonCompilerOptions)engine.GetCompilerOptions();
        //compilerOptions.Module = IronPython.Runtime.ModuleOptions.co
        //ErrorSink errorSink = null;
        //ErrorListener errorListener = new ErrorSinkProxyListener(errorSink);
        //var scriptSource = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"C:\Nidec\PythonScript\download_nrlist.py", Encoding.UTF8, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceCodeKind.File);
        //var compiledCode = scriptSource.Compile();
        //compiledCode.Execute(scope);
        //engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Nidec\PythonScript\download_nrlist.py", scope);

        //get function and dynamically invoke
        //var calcAdd = scope.GetVariable("CalcAdd");
        //result = calcAdd(34, 8); // returns 42 (Int32)
     
       //get values from external class library
        DatasetValues datasetValues = new DatasetValues();
        DataTable dt = datasetValues.GetDatasetValues();
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[i][j]);

            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to first check the error. What OS do you based on? WIndows or linux?

Comment: The 500 error is not helpful to solve this problem, you need to check the specific error of the azure function.

Comment: Question here is with deployment? Do i need to deploy external call library also along with azure function?

Comment: Can you go to the log to check the specific error? You can use application insights or kudu.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 500 error is not helpful to solve this problem, you need to check the specific error of the azure function. You can use application insights to get the details error. The function must configure the corresponding application insights before you can view the log on the portal.

So you need to configure an application insights to your function app like this:

[image]

Then your function app will restart.

Of course, you can also go to kudu to view:

First, go to advanced tools, then click 'GO',

[image]

Then After you go to kudu, click Debug Console -> CMD -> LogFiles -> Application -> Functions -> yourtriggername. You will find log file there.

If you are based on linux OS, after go to kudu, just click 'log stream'(this is not supportted to consumption plan for linux.).

Answer (score 0):

Libraries and packages for your project are defined in project.json and installed automatically when you deploy your function to Azure.

Comment: I have created azure function in Visual Studio, where is project.json? Do i need to add manually?

Comment: In Visual Studio look for Dependencies -> Packages in your Solution Explorer

Comment: where is project.json? I couldn't find anywhere in solution.

Comment: you won´t see any project.json in Visual Studio, just all your package dependencies under Dependencies -> Packages